# Convert youtube video to mp3 using Quick MP3 API

Tags: php, api, youtube, mp3

I need convert youtube video to mp3 using Quick MP3 API.

http://www.quick-mp3.com/api/v1/docs/

my code example is :

```
<?php
$url="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpgTC9MDx1o";
// i need to fetch video informations and get mp3 download link
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: you try the code php in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code :
don't forgot to include quick_func.php in your php code

```
require_once('./quick_func.php'); // quick mp3 functions
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpgTC9MDx1o";
$exp = explode("?v=",$url);
$vid = $exp[1]; 
$data = Convert_Vid($vid); // video id to convert
$id = $data['id']; // get video id
$title = $data['ttl']; // get video title
$duration = $data['duration']; // get video duration
$thumb = $data['thumb']; // get video thumb
$mp3 = $data['mp3']; // get mp3 download link
print_r($data);
```

you need to transform your full youtube url to video ID :

```
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpgTC9MDx1o"; // full youtube url
$exp = explode("?v=",$url); // explode url
$vid = $exp[1]; // get id after ?v=
```

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should try below API to get mp3 format of any YouTube video as quick-mp3 is no more available.

```html
<iframe id="buttonApi" src="https://convert2mp3s.com/api/button/mp3?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRpeEdMmmQ0" width="100%" height="100%" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" style="border:none"></iframe>
```

GitHub Project: https://github.com/matthew-asuncion/Fast-YouTube-to-MP3-Converter-API